# When the css overflow is set on my content, the div slides down

Tags: html, css

I've got the following html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainframe">
      <ul>
        <li><a href='news.shtml'><img src='tastenews.jpg' alt='News'/></a></li>
        <li><a href='demo.shtml'><img src='tastedemos.jpg' alt='Demos'/></a></li>
        <li><a href='index.shtml'><img src='tastehome.jpg' alt='home'/></a></li>
      </ul> 
      <div id="content">
        <h1>News</h1>
        <div class="news">
           <p class="date">10. April 2011</p>
           <p>
         First News
           </p>
        </div>

        <div class="news">
           <p class="date">09. Feb. 2011</p>
           <p>
         Second News
           </p>
        </div>

        <!-- etc... -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the following style:

```
body
{
background-color:black;
text-align:center;
margin:50px 0px;
padding:0px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#mainframe
{
width:940px;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:left;
padding:15px;
}

#content
{
position: relative;
top: 0;
background-image:url('hintergrund.jpg');
height:491px;
width:800px;
overflow:auto;
}

.news .date
{
font-weight:bold;
float:left;
width:150px;
}

ul
{
float:right;
list-style:none;
margin:1px; 
}

img
{
border:0;
}
```

If the content of the content div exceed the 491px height, the it is pushed down under the level of the last menu button. Why does it do so, and how can I correct it? I've tested with Firefox and Safari under MAC OS X.

Comment: Not seeing what you mean, FF5 Win7: http://jsfiddle.net/shanethehat/sSxcE/

Comment: @shanethehat what about [here](http://kingdom7.free.fr/melanie/news.shtml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that the `ul` has 40px of left padding, which is making the remaining space too narrow for the content area.  Try adding a rule to the `ul` to remove the unnecessary padding:

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't bring anything, might it be because I didn't remove the clear element I added after the other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Definitely remove that too.

Comment: Ok, it works like that. I have a few question: How did you detect the issue with the padding? What is this `outside` value for the list-style? And why didn't the clear property work in this case?

Comment: I found the issue using Firefox with the Firebug extension.  If you don't have it, get it. It's an essential tool for web development.  Using it you can select each element and have it's box model properties highlighted. List-style outside refers to the placement of the bullets/numbers of a list, either inside or outside the elements box.

Comment: The clear property didn't work because you placed a div between your nav and your content with it's clear set to `both`, which essentially said 'ensure there are no elements to either side of this`. Because your content was after this div, it had to sit underneath it, and the clearing div could never sit alongside a float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear after ul... Just use a clear class and use it after ul like this

Clear class will be like this

.clear {
clear: both:
}

Comment: I've tried giving the clear class to the content div, and adding an empty div with clear class after the ul tag. But it didn't bring anything.

Comment: You didn't close it correctly btw: <div class="clear"></class>

Comment: @Semyazas: now it's closed correctly, but still didn't help. Note that I added the style suggested by shanethehat, so Is there maybe a conflict?